# Solving Trigonometry Equation with powers

Tags: trigonometry

I am having difficulty understanding how to solve $3\tan^2{\theta} - 1 = 0$

Putting $ t = \tan\theta $, I get $ t = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt3} $. Is that done ? How to find angle $\theta$ now?

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Narasimham Adding work which the OP has not expressed falls afoul of the "don't change the meaning of posts when editing" rule. Please refrain from making such edits.

Comment: @epimorphic. OK thanks, I am prepared to restore to s.q.a. It was not moving  forward, so thought may be it would help.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$3\tan^2\theta-1=0 \iff \left(\tan \theta - \frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\left(\tan \theta + \frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

You can split it this way
$$3\tan(o)^2-1=(\sqrt3\tan(o)-1)(\sqrt3\tan(o)+1)=0$$
so you have to solve both $$\sqrt3\tan(o)-1=0$$ and $$\sqrt3\tan(o)+1=0$$.

Comment: $\sqrt3\tan(o)+1=0$ can be replaced by $\sqrt3\tan(\theta)+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$3\tan^2\theta-1=0 $$

$$ \left(\tan \theta - \frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\left(\tan \theta + \frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=0$$

$$ \theta =\pm \tan^{-1} \frac {1}{\sqrt3} $$

$$ \theta = \pm \pi/6 $$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have terms containing the square of sine, cosine or tangent etc.

use $$\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}$$

Finally $\cos2A=\cos2B\implies2A=2m\pi\pm2B$ where $m$ is any integer