# How can we use an identity to solve the equation $1-\tan^2 \theta = \frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $1- \tan^ 2\theta = \frac{2}{3}$, then find the value of $\theta.$

I cannot understand which identity fits there. What must be used to find the value of $\theta$ ?

Comment: Solve for $\tan\theta$ first.

Comment: @tapadianewlon, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217025/solving-trigonometry-equation-with-powers

Comment: First of all solve for $ \tan \theta $ and  then find out all $ \theta$ s.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $ 1-\tan^2\theta=\frac{2}{3}$
$\Rightarrow \tan^2\theta=\frac{1}{3}$ $\Rightarrow \tan\theta=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}$ $\Rightarrow \theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pm\pi}{6}$

Comment: You can obtain $\tan\theta$ by typing \tan\theta between dollar signs.

Comment: how can we write arctan in latex

Comment: To produce $\arctan x$, write \arctan x between dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

May be you thought $1+ \tan^ 2 \theta $ simplifies to ready made $ \sec^2 \theta$ and so on,but you should be prepared to process it further without ready mades.

In this case you see that $ \tan \theta = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3. },\rightarrow\theta = \frac{\pm \pi}{6}. $

Answer (score 0):

The identity you have in mind is $1 + \tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$.  While we can use it to solve the problem, it is simpler to solve the problem directly.
\begin{align*}
1 - \tan^2\theta & = \frac{2}{3}\\
-\tan^2\theta & = -\frac{1}{3}\\
\tan^2\theta & = \frac{1}{3}\\
\tan\theta & = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\theta & = \arctan\left(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\theta & = \pm \frac{\pi}{6} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
If we use the identity $1 + \tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
1 - \tan^2\theta & = \frac{2}{3}\\
-\tan^2\theta & = -\frac{1}{3}\\
-(\sec^2\theta - 1) & = -\frac{1}{3}\\
\sec^2\theta - 1 & = \frac{1}{3}\\
\sec^2\theta & = \frac{4}{3}\\
\cos^2\theta & = \frac{3}{4}\\
\cos\theta & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \cos\theta & = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\theta & = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
-\dfrac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}
& \theta & = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{5\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\dfrac{7\pi}{6} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
As you can verify, the solution sets are equivalent.